# Why is my background image always disappearing when I log in?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, desktop-background

When logging in lubuntu 12.04, my background image always disappears, leaving the screen with color only and then I have to go to definitions and set the image in the background again.

I notice that this does not happen with low-resolution images, only with high ones, but also happens with images that fit my screen resolution (1280 X 720).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

The image remains at it's location, but on the desktop preferences, the pathway to the file location is lost and set to `none`.

Comment: No, the image remains at it's location, but on the desktop preferences, the pathway to the file location is lost and set to <none>.

Comment: did you fool around with the `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks` directory? (do you have that directory?). btw! Feel free to edit it into your question so we can delete the comments ;)

Comment: what's the cut-off? Are images slightly greater than 1280x720 doing this? What about slightly smaller? Have you tried copying the background image to `/usr/share/backgrounds` (copy it as root) and loading it as background image for your desktop from there?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, after upgrading to 12.04.

Comment: @EDi did you try titaniumtux' suggestion? I assume that this is a bug which should be reportet at launchpad.

Comment: yes, but no success :(

Comment: It happens sometimes after selecting the image from other partitions (mostly NTFS which needs mounting) , in my case when changed wallpaper doesn't shows up on Desktop , trying the zoom, tile ,center , scale options from Appearance menu helps out.

Comment: The picture is present at the the log in screen, then after log in disappears. I can change it the manually in the Appearance menu, but this changes do not survive the next boot :(

Comment: Do you use any remote desktop tools such as XRDP or similar since these often try to remove backgrounds to speed things up, but they can tend to be buggy..

Comment: Well meanwhile I uninstalled Lubuntu but the problem was never solved... I still have no clue on why this happened... but I tried moving the images to home folder instead of getting them from other partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  When I login, I get a black screen as if the image has been deleted.  Then I figured out that it was a permission issue.  So I went into the permission tab, and changed Group, and Other permissions to Read and Write, and that fixed it.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksudo nautilus
```

When it comes up navigate to `/usr/share/backgrounds`and change the permissions from the permission tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe image's path didn't have the right permissions, try to move one to your Pictures directory and tell me if it still get lost on new sessions.

If that's the problem you could set the rigth permissions to your images's folder running:

> gksu nautilus

and through the properties dialog set permissions for your user to read-whrite that directory, remember to press apply to enclosed files button.