# My desktop Wallpaper keeps Disappearing whenever i Log in.?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, desktop-background

I m using ubuntu 12.04, gnome classic and whenever i log in my wallpaper disappears leaving only black screen
I did visit this thread

[Why is my background image always disappearing when I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139959/why-is-my-background-image-always-disappearing-when-i-log-in)

but it didnt help me! 
please if any one could fix this!

Comment: Where is the wall paper stored? In another partition?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your wallpapers to the Pictures subfolder of your home folder. Right-click on the desktop and click *Change Desktop Background*. Select *picutre* instead of *wallpaper*. All your wallpapers (in the Pictures folder) will appear. Select one as your background.