# Cannot add folder to boot drive

Tags: unity, directory, filemanager

My boot drive is a 1TB drive and is working fine. Another 1TB drive is acting a bit flaky so I want to move some data (200GB) from my flaky drive to a folder on my boot drive (900GB free on my boot drive).

Using the Unity DE, I click on "Computer" on the left and I see lots of folders but I am unable to create a new folder here. I tried the File menu but New Folder is disabled.

I can create folders under my profile but this is data I would prefer not be under my profile.

Is there a way to add folders on the boot drive without those folders being under my home directory? If there is not, must I re-partition my boot drive to be able to use all of the empty space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not root when you browse your files by default (for obvious security reasons).

**You can run `gksu nautilus` to launch nautilus as root**

What I did is adding a shortcut to launch this :

1. Open `System Settings` and go to `Keyboard` ;
2. Under `Shortcut` > `Custom Shortcuts` click the <kbd>+</kbd> (add) button ;
3. Name the shortcut as you like and fill the above command (`gksu nautilus`), then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> button ;
4. Click on <kbd>Disabled</kbd> next to the new shortcut and pick key combination of your choosing.

It will prompt for your password every time you open this.

Comment: One more question that is directly related to this solution. When I do this, it removed my desktop background as soon as I entered my password. When I closed the window, it did not put my background back. Any way to avoid this side-effect?

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't experienced this side-effect... Was it back after reboot? And if so, does it happen again when open re-open Nautilus as root?

Comment: The background did return after reboot (but not after logout). Each time I use the hotkey ( Ctrl + \ ) it removes my background. At least it's repeatable (on my machine - 16.04)

Comment: Try using a different shortcut, maybe this one do something else in addition... (Or does it happen even when you run the command from the terminal ?)

Comment: It happens even when I run from the terminal.

Comment: Since I don't get this issue, I can only link you [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139959/why-is-my-background-image-always-disappearing-when-i-log-in?noredirect=1&lq=1) and hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for following up. That thread's solution did nothing for me. Still happy that my original problem is solved.